# Entity Framework Code First - Multiple Nullable Relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Code:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
    public virtual int? DocumentId { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
    public virtual int DocumentId { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Document is an entity type that I am referring to from several other entities. In entity A it is optional, and for entity B it is required for B to exist. A Document will only ever be referenced from a single class A, B, C, etc. and won't ever be referenced by more than one.

So the FK/fields AId and BId in the Document table should both be nullable.

I can't seem to get the configuration right, EF is complaining it can't work out the principal of the relationship.

This is my best attempt so far, but doesn't work:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.Document)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal();

        modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Document)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're supposed to configure it with `HasForeignKey` first.